# Use underscore (_) in joomla menu alias

Tags: joomla

I want to use underscore in menu alias in joomla. For a menu item called "Residential Storage" I want to use "residential_storage" as alias but when I save this it becomes "residential-storage", so underscore is being replaced by hyphen. How can I use hyphen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the alias should consist of lowercase letters and hyphens (-). No blank spaces or underscores are allowed.But to use  underscore check the link below.This method will replace all (-)  to (_). 
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=618&t=638854