# Joomla 3.x: How to allow underscore in menu item aliases

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

Unfortunately, Joomla 3.x *replaces underscore in menu item alias with hyphen*.

How can I allow underscore? [without sh404SEF].

I don't see it in `libraries/joomla/filter/output.php` (as the page [Use underscore (_) in joomla menu alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717253/use-underscore-in-joomla-menu-alias) says).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that file there is the line:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\s|[^A-Za-z0-9\-])+/', '-', $str);
```

Put _ between z and 0

Comment: the folder libraries/joomla/filter doesn't exist

Comment: @Entretoize yeah, it doesn't exist in the latest version of Joomla, but it DOES exist in that Joomla 3.x I had wrote about in 2015